# python: conditinoally splitting a string

Tags: python

there are lots of questions about split in python, but I couldn't find
corresponding to my problem. I want to split a string, but need to have
different values for the splitter, depending on a condition. For the test
case, my string is "11xx22xx33xxBEGINxx44xx55xxENDxx66xx77". I want to
process this string in chunks, meaning I want to step through it like
this:

split off '11', do something with it

split off '22', do something with it

split off '33', do something with it

split off 'BEGINxx44xx55xxEND', do something with it

split off '66', do something with it

split off '77', do something with it

I tried a recursive function:

```
import string

mystring = "11xx22xx33xxBEGINxx44xx55xxENDxx66xx77"

def makechunks(s):
    try: splitter
    except NameError:
        splitter = "xx"
    whole = s.split(splitter, 1)
    current = whole[0]
    try: whole[1]
    except NameError:
        return
    else:
        rest = whole[1]
        if current.find("BEGIN", 0, 5):
            splitter = "END"
        else:
            splitter = "xx"
        makechunks(rest)
        print("AA", current, "BB")

makechunks(mystring)
```

But I'm getting the error "list index out of range." Maybe my entire
approach is flawed, and there are better ways to achieve what I want? I'll
be grateful for any hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
matches = re.findall('(?:^|xx)(BEGIN.*?END|.*?)(?=xx|$)', s)
```

Result:

```
['11', '22', '33', 'BEGINxx44xx55xxEND', '66', '77']
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Otag1)

Comment: Thank you, this is a neat solution for the example I made, but it would be difficult to scale in real life if there are arbitrary repetitions of "regular" and "BEGIN ... END" blocks. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @Thomas: Why would it be difficult "to scale"? Can you give an example of a valid input string where the regular expression doesn't do what you want? And also post what you do want for that example input string.

Comment: How embarrassing - I had just assumed that this would go through the string only once, but I just tried, and it will in fact extract all the matches, and it is possible (if a bit hard to read) to add further regular expressions. For example: `mystring = "11xxBEGINxx22xx33xxENDxx66xxSTARTxx77xx88xxSTOPxx99"` and then `matches = re.findall('(?:^|xx)(BEGIN.*?END|START.*?STOP|.*?)(?=xx|$)', mystring)` works too. Thanks a lot, your code works wonderfully and provides a great way to do what I want!

Answer (score 1):

What about splitting them all and then joining all the ones between BEGIN and END?

```
ssplit = mystring.split("xx")
bIndex = ssplit.index("BEGIN")
eIndex = ssplit.index("END")
bend = "xx".join(ssplit[bIndex:eIndex+1])
others = ssplit[:bIndex] + ssplit[eIndex+1:]
```

now you have your BEGIN..END token in 'bend' and the remaining tokens in 'others'

Comment: This approach seems more appropriate for what I want to do; I have played a bit with it, and I can make it do what I want. Thanks!